# Restore a deleted windows active directory user

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2

### The Problem

In our Windows Active Directory, i have cleaned up our records and deleted a lot of inactive users. It turns out that a user i deleted is still needed by one of our staff. I know that it's possible to restore the user from:

> Active Directory Administrative Center > Server (local) > Deleted
>   Objects.

But, the Active Directory recycle bin is not active. I have heard about some powershell commands too but i don't want to start messing with that since i'm not experienced in that field.

### The Question

Is it possible to restore the deleted user back into the Active Directory, even though the Active Directory recycle bin isn't enabled?

We are using Windows Server 2012 R2.

Thank you.

Comment: In addition, if this is possible, how long do i have until it's irreversable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that there are two kinds of deleted objects in AD. If you had Recycle Bin enabled, you could restore the original account almost unaltered (except for groups). But if you don't have Recycle Bin, then AD still keeps so-called *tombstone* objects, which have almost all information stripped off.

Fortunately tombstone objects still retain the user account SID, so you can restore the account and have it be recognized as the same account. It seems you'll need an LDAP client such as *ldp* or *adsiedit* or *ADS* to achieve this:

- https://www.itprotoday.com/windows-78/ad-tombstone-objects

Comment: Thanks grawity. I'm not that experienced with AD so will need to go away and research what you've suggested.